# How to configure RockMongo for Mongo replicaSet

Tags: php, mongodb, ide

I recently switched to the [RockMongo browser](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=rockmongo), but I am having a hard time making it work with a replicaSet.

Per [the official documentation](http://code.google.com/p/rock-php/wiki/configuration), I declared the server as:

```
$MONGO["servers"][$i]["mongo_name"] = "localhost";//mongo server name
$MONGO["servers"][$i]["mongo_host"] = "127.0.0.1";//mongo host
$MONGO["servers"][$i]["mongo_port"] = "27017";//mongo port
$MONGO["servers"][$i]["mongo_timeout"] = 0;//mongo connection timeout
```

RockMongo complains with the following:

```
Execute failed:not master
function (){ return db.getCollectionNames(); }
```

I also tried another variant which resulted in the same error:

```
$MONGO["servers"][$i]["mongo_host"] = "mongodb://192.168.0.2,192.168.0.3";// multiple hosts
```

Can RockMongo work with a replicaSet?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

But if you dive into the source code, you find that rockmongo can indeed connect to replicaSet using undocumented "mongo_options" key :

```
$MONGO["servers"][$i]["mongo_options"] = array('replicaSet' => 'REPLICA_NAME');//mongo server name
$MONGO["servers"][$i]["mongo_host"] = "mongodb://192.168.0.2,192.168.0.3";//mongo host
$MONGO["servers"][$i]["mongo_port"] = false;//mongo port
```

Hope this helps !

Comment: Here is the document: http://rockmongo.com/wiki/configuration?lang=en_us#%23%23%23%23+mongo_options%0D